# What is the best way to have multiple gaming consoles on the same network?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, gaming

I'm trying to set up my gaming consoles (one Nintendo Switch and two PS4's) to be able to play games online.  However, I cant seem to get any port forwarding rules to work on the Switch or the PlayStations simultaneously; port forwarding only forwards the port to one specific IP and the consoles require the same ports to connect to the game servers.

Is there some way to connect all three at the same time while not having to open up all those ports on my router firewall?

Comment: what happens when you try to use them all at the same time without any port forwarding?

Comment: they all cannot connect to game server when loading up game, but playstation network connects successfully, it says " Failed to connect to game server. Please try again later" as for the switch when connecting to online multiplayer it also says, " A communication error has occurred, Please try again later"  with error code 2618-0201

Comment: are there different PSN accounts on each PlayStation?

Comment: yea but playstation network isnt the issue, the issue is connecting to the actuall game servers to play online multiplayer.

Comment: Testing internet connection everything is successful on ps4, IP , internet connection and playstation network sign in.

Comment: For this exact problem, I believe UPnP can solve that. This let's the consoles open the ports dynamically and without clashing with other consoles.

Comment: UPnP is enabled and still did not fix the problem, i got it working tho nonetheless, i had to add the ip and mac to the trusted list so that it can dynamically open ports as needed. Through lots of frustration it was an easy fix.

Comment: @Poiuyt - If you are double NAT'd then UPnP won't work.  Is your modem assigned a public or private IP address (simplest way to determine if your behind a ISP NAT).  **As you have found you can't forward a port to multiple devices.**  So you will need a single device, that does not have a firewall configured, that other devices can connect to.  This way all traffic to that device will be sent over a port that is already open.